# Real Numbers Raised to Imaginary Powers?

Tags: complex-numbers

What is a real number to the power of an imaginary or complex number? e.g. 3<sup>i</sup>. I have searched through sites about imaginary numbers, but none seem to say anything about imaginary indices. Examples and explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/complexexp.html

Comment: Provided the "real number" raised to a complex power is positive, this is well-defined.  (Zero raised to a complex power is left as an exercise for the Reader.)

Comment: See also here: http://www.milefoot.com/math/complex/exponentofi.htm It is not really a secret.

Comment: This is question rally “off-topic”?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The basic formula is $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, so your example would be

$$3^i=e^{i\ln3}=\cos(\ln3)+i\sin(\ln3)$$

Answer (score 9):

Using euler's formula :

$$c^{a+bi}=c^ac^{bi}=c^ae^{bi \ln (c)}$$

$$=c^a \left((\cos (b \ln (c))+ i \sin(b \ln (c) \right))$$